# Discrete signals in spectrum to Analog : DFT

Tags: dft

An analog signal $x(t)$ was sampled for a period $T$ of $1 \text{ms}$. The resulting, discrete signal is denoted as $x[n]$. Now you are given the spectrum $X[k]$ of the sampled signal $x[n]$.

Doubts regarding the attached images 1 & 2.

Please explain how this coefficients and signs for sin and cos term are considered??

[image: Im 1]
[image: Im 2]

Comment: Please, add the images to your post

Comment: @MaximGi I cannot add images, as I dont have reputation to do so. I have  attached the  images.. you must be seeing links. Please click on the links to view the images.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QNbhx.png
[2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rMpAj.png

Comment: I did the edit, I didnt know there was a reputation requirement for images

Comment: Are you sure about the sampling time ? 1 ms gives us 1000 Hz sampling, which is lower than both 2000 Hz 3000 Hz ? isn't it 0.1 ms or 1 µs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For signal 1 ($x_1(t)$) :
The Fourier's transform ($F(f)$) of $Acos(2\pi ft)$ is $\frac{A}{2}(\delta(f-f_0)+\delta(f+f_0))$ and for $Asin(2\pi ft)$ it's $\frac{jA}{2}(\delta(f-f_0)-\delta(f+f_0))$

Replacing frequencies and amplitudes with the appropriate ones, the Fourier's transform of $x_1(t)$ is :
$$
F(f) = \delta(f-3000 Hz)+\delta(f+3000 Hz)+\frac{j}{2}\left(\delta(f-2000 Hz)-\delta(f+2000 Hz)\right)
$$

Hence the observed Diracs on fig. 1. You did not scale your axis according to the fft sampling while plotting it so the frequency does not appear clearly. The amplitudes are respectively 4 and 8 which is the right ratio so I guess you also did not scale the fft result (matlab doesnt do it itself), it should be 0.5 and 1 according to what I calculated.

For signal 2 it works the same way

edit : there is a mistake in the sampling frequency (1 kHz) you mention. To fit the graphs properly (and respect Shanon) it should be 8 KHz.

Comment: Maxim, according to OP's statement of a sampling period of 1 ms, there is an apparent aliasing in the obtained samples x[n] of the signal x(t). I guess you should at least mention about this in your answer...

Comment: I asked him in a comment above, I think it's just a reporting mistake and it was 0.1 ms or something else

Comment: You can check this by observing whether the coefficient places fit for an assumed 0.1ms of sampling...

Comment: I edited. Am I a better person now ?

Comment: @MaximGi thank you .. yes frequency is 8 KHz.